# select the date from one table that not exist in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have 2 tables

```
Matricule   date
248         31/01/2017
248         01/02/2017
248         02/02/2017
```

second table:

```
matricule  date_effet
248        30/01/2017
248        31/01/2017
248        01/02/2017
248        02/02/2017
```

what i want  is to extract the the date that exist on the second one and don't exist in the first one in this case 30/01/2017 knowing  that the user will select a range date for exemple in this case maybe date  between 28/01/2017 and 02/02/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything so far?
Something like this will probably work for you;

```
    SELECT matricule, date
    FROM FirstTable
    WHERE date >= @StartDate AND date <= @EndDate
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT matricule, date_effet AS date
    FROM SecondTable
    WHERE date_effet >= @StartDate AND date_effet <= @EndDate
```

Edit: Okay seems MySQL doesn't support Except? Sure it did....

This should work then;

```
SELECT matricule, date_effet 
FROM SecondTable 
WHERE date_effet>= @StartDate AND date_effet<= @EndDate
AND date NOT IN 
(
    SELECT date 
    FROM FirstTable
    WHERE date >= @StartDate AND date <= @EndDate
);
```

Comment: thanks for the responce. I just tried it but except is not supported by mysql

Comment: thnks  bro it worked this is my final query    SELECT matricule, date_effet as date FROM presence WHERE date_effet BETWEEN '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-28' and matricule=248 and( date_effet not in (SELECT date as date FROM activites WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-28')) order by date_effet

Comment: Good stuff! Glad you got sorted